# Magento 2.2.1 site migration from live to local win 10 wamp server, but path jump to the domain name

Tags: wamp

Magento 2.2.1 site migration from live to local win 10 wamp server, but path jump to the domain name?
1. I have modified the path in the data
2. Clean up the var/cache cache
3. app/etc/env.php also points to the mysql database
But after I type: 127.0.0.1/public_html, it jumps directly to the domain name. May I ask what is the reason?
[image]

[image]

Comment: if you are using chrome it is because of the chrome browser cache. try running it on incognito and check

Comment: i use chrome, firefox, ie edge, and clear browser cache, but it still happen this question.